# WPF Youtube app running on Windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, youtube-api

I'm building a WPF application that should be able to play Youtube videos. But there are some problems running the app on Windows 7.

When I follow the article by [Sacha Barber](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/YouViewer.aspx) it shows a pop-up saying "File download security warning" which isn't very nice, I don't want the user to have to click ok every time.

Then there's a second approach. Use the WebBrowser's NavigateToString property and enter there a full HTML code for a page that plays the Youtube video. Unfortunately, that doesn't work for me at all, all I see is a black space where the video should be.

Have you ever come across anything like this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple YouTube video viewer in WPF, and went down the NavigateToString route and built up the web page source by hand, using the embed code provided by YouTube, and this worked a treat (other than the fact several of the videos on YouTube are marked as unable to embed, so you get a link to view on the full site instead).  I created an attached property to avoid any code behind too.

What is the code you are using?